# this.props.history.push showing error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have checked so many answers but still i am getting this error.

```
import JobListing from './JobListing.jsx';
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
const history = createHistory();`

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({keyword: this.state.value,country: 
    this.state.selectedOption,showForm : false});
    this.props.history.push('/joblisting');
}
```

Comment: You need to know react.js well before you going to routing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are refering to this.props.history whereas you define a locally scoped history const:

Change your:

```
this.props.history.push('/joblisting');
```

to:

```
history.push('/joblisting');
```

Comment: But why is it not working, any JS error? Or just not doing what you're expecting it to do?